# Get The Substring From Path Directory

Tags: regex, string, path, c#-3.0

I want the substring from the Directory path.
Is there any query or Regex to do that.
The path i have is like this:

```
E:\\Work\\Taxonomies\\012\\20110826\\20110826_final\\full_entry_point_2011-08-26.xsd
```

What i want is

```
20110826_final\\full_entry_point_2011-08-26.xsd
```

I want the path from the second last "\" i can split it in array but then i have to combine the last two values.

```
string[] path = value.Split('\\');
int length=path.Length;
if(length>1)
{
 string final = string.Concat(path[length-2],"\\", path[length-1]);
}
```

please guide me on this. Is there any other way to implement it.

Comment: Does `value.Substring(32)` not work for you?

Comment: I don't think he has a fixed length.

Comment: @Loamhoof `Substring()` removes from the start of the string, not from the end.

Comment: @  Loamhoof thats right the string length is not fixed.

Comment: Ok, so he may have a fixed length from the beginning, but still not sure.

Comment: @  Tomalak string length is not fixed.I have the approach which i followed.

Comment: @  Tomalak.Can i go with my approach or is there any better way around.Please guide me on this sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String pattern = @"(.*\\)(.*\\.*$)";
String input = @"E:\Work\Taxonomies\012\20110826\20110826_final\full_entry_point_2011-08-26.xsd";
String result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[2].Value;
```

**Edit**

This regex divides string in two groups. 
First - all the symbols and \ it could take before second group.
Second - all the remaining symbols which are 'text'\'text''endofstring'

Comment: One thing. It behaves bad, when the file is not in folder like `'E:\1.txt'`. What do you expect in this situation?

Comment: Does it handle the scenario you just mentioned now..Please explain the meaning of the regex if possible so that i can implement mine in future..

Comment: What string do you want to have, when you have E:\\1.txt input?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know C#, you will maybe have a deal with the number of "\", but, if you want to do it with a regex:

```
/(?<=\\\\)[^\\]+\\\\[^\\]+$/
```

That is "one or more characters preceded by 2 backslashes, then 2 backslashes, then one or more characters until the end". When I mean character, I mean everything but a backslash.

Comment: This result is similar to array collection which i get after splitting the value by "\\".

Comment: Thanks for the effort :).I wanted to know if any other ways are better than the one i have mentioned.

Comment: As I said, I don't know C#, but find it kinda weird that it would not simply return a string, as there is no group in this regex, and one match only possible, I don't see what it could return instead :o

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to using regular expressions for this searching operation is to use the LastIndexOf method on the String class thus:

```
    static bool TryFindTrailingPart(string path, int numberOfSeparators, out string result)
    {
        var sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        var lastSlash = path.Length;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSeparators; i++)
        {
            lastSlash = path.LastIndexOf(sep, lastSlash - 1);
            if(lastSlash < 0)
            {
                result = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        result = path.Substring(lastSlash + 1);
        return true;
    }
```

Although this code is substantially longer than a regular expression, it does have some advantages: it is somewhat more flexible than the regular expression approach (having parameterized the number of path separators to search for), and it executes substantially faster.

Running the above code in a tight loop with the OP's path expression takes around 200 milliseconds for 10000 iterations.

Using the regular expression approach given in Dmitry Dovgopoly's answer for the same number of iterations takes around 6890 milliseconds.  Converting Dmitry's code to use a compiled regular expression (and excluding the time required to compile the expression) still takes around 3140 milliseconds.

Whether or not the speed and flexibility of this approach outweighs the increase in source code length largely depends upon your specific scenario: if you are processing (very!) large numbers of path strings, it might be useful.  On the other hand, if you just need a "single use" piece of code to handle the path string processing problem, the regular expression approach is perhaps more appropriate.